# Android Dagger 2 POJO field Inject null

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Just started using Dagger 2 today and I'm a bit confused on how exactly I need to set everything up.

I'm trying to inject a POJO, but it's always null.
First, some code:

App.java

```
private AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
}

public AppComponent component() {
    return appComponent;
}
```

AppModule.java

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Application app;

    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public Application application() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App application);
    Application application();
}
```

NetworkingManager.java

```
@Singleton
public class NetworkingManager {
    private Context ctx;

    @Inject
    public NetworkingManager(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }
}
```

NetModule.java

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    public NetworkingManager provideNetworkingManager(Application application) {
        return new NetworkingManager(application);
    }
}
```

NetComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetModule.class},
        dependencies = {AppModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(NetworkingManager networkingManager);
}
```

SomeClass.java

```
@Inject
NetworkingManager networkingManager;

public void doSomethingWithNetworkManager() {
    networkManager.doStuff();
}
```

I've spent a good deal of time looking through lots of tutorials, SO questions, and examples, but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm 99% certain I have something setup wrong, but I haven't been able to figure out what.

Comment: It seems that you have a bit of confusion. What is your goal? Where are you trying to use `NetworkingManager`?

Comment: NetworkManager is currently a singleton. It handles all the async networking. It's used all over the place. My goal is to eliminate the singleton and switch to DI, as well as make the class testable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to make `NetworkingManager` available everywhere in your application.

Let's start with your definition of the `Component`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App application);
}
```

This tells Dagger that this component will be injecting the `App` class.  Now here you can also tell Dagger other classes you would like to inject. So if you want to also inject an `Activity` for example you would add:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App application);
    void inject(MainActivity activity) //Where MainActivity is a class that extends Activity.
}
```

Please note that this is not the best way, IMO, to share Application wide dependencies; you should create a `Component` that inherits from `AppComponent` and make `AppComponent` expose the desired shared dependencies.

Now let's look at your module class:

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    public NetworkingManager provideNetworkingManager(Application application) {
        return new NetworkingManager(application);
    }
}
```

Here you are `@Provide`ing a `NetworkingManager`, that is fine. Your `NetworkingManager` requires an `Application` (a `Context` really), why not provide `App` inside of `NetworkingManager`?, or even better why not provide `NetworkingManager` inside the `AppModule` since `AppModule` should `@Provide` things that are common for the whole `Application`:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Application app;

    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public Application application() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public NetworkingManager provideNetworkingManager(Application application) {
        return new NetworkingManager(application);
    }
}
```

Now inside your `App` class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
   appComponent.inject(this);
}

public AppComponent component() {
    return appComponent;
 }
}
```

And in our hypothetical `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AppComponent appComponent;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    appComponent = ((App)getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent();
    appComponent.inject(this);
   }
 }
```

It seems that you are not using `@Component(dependencies = {...})` correctly. `dependencies` is used when you want to expose a dependency from one `Component` to another using the mechanism I mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more sense. 1) I assume in `App.onCreate()` you meant `.build()` and not `.inject(this)`, as `inject()` returns void. 2) `NetworkingManager` is in a different package than `App`. I was thinking it would be better to keep separate modules for each package. Is that not possible? 3) Getting the `AppComponent` in `MainActivity.onCreate()` is fine for activities & fragments. What about POJOs that don't have access to the application context? Do I have to get the context in an activity first and pass it to the POJO? That seems backwards to the point of DI with Dagger.

Comment: 1) You are right, I fixed the `App` code.  You would call `inject()` if you want to also inject `App`. 2) You can definitely have different modules per package, but I think it makes more sense to have different modules per scope (Application level, Activity level, etc). 3) For POJOs you can just annotate their constructor with `@Inject` if they are being used from a class that was already injected by a `Component`. This can be confusing to grasp. We can talk more about it if you want on a chat room.