# Null reference on Dagger 2 @Inject

Tags: firebase, mvp, dagger-2

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/reustonium/3f14dd5ed7fc03b93180) highlighting the issue I'm running into.  I'm using an Application Module to provide a `Firebase` dependency for me to inject elsewhere.

When I try to `@Inject Firebase mFirebase` in the data layer that dependency is never satisfied.

I'm trying to keep the `Context` out of my other layers, but the `Firebase` service depends on it.  I'm interested in learning any other patterns to help keep `Android` classes out of my business logic.

**FirebaseService.java**

```
public class FirebaseService {

@Inject Firebase mFirebaseRef; //NEVER GET'S INJECTED!

    @Override
    public LoginResult signinWithEmail(final String email, final String password) {
      mFirebaseRef.dostuff(); //THIS REFERENCE DOESN'T GET INJECTED!
    }
}
```

**ApplicationModule**

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Firebase provideFirebase(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
    return new Firebase(Util.FIREBASE_URL);
}
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @ApplicationContext Context context();
    Application application();
    Firebase firebase();
}
```

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityComponent mActivityComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ActivityComponent getActivityComponent() {
    if (mActivityComponent == null) {
        mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                .applicationComponent(MyApplication.get(this).getComponent())
                .build();
    }
    return mActivityComponent;
}
```

The full code example is on [github](https://github.com/reustonium/Lunch-Pals/tree/Login)

Comment: Having links to the code is not enough, since links tend to rot (plus it requires us to go out to another site and read). Please add the minimum code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotating a field with `@Inject` is not enough for the field injection to work. There's no magic involved, you just have to tell Dagger to do the injection.

First, add this method to your `ApplicationComponent`:

```
void inject(FirebaseService firebaseService);
```

Then, call this method from your `FirebaseService` (I guess it's an Android service, so add this to the `onCreate` method):

```
applicationComponent.inject(this);
```

This should do the trick. There's a great answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540757/1348215).

**EDIT**

I've looked at your repository and I think you don't even need field injection in this case. You can just provide the `Firebase` dependency through a constructor. Here's your `@Provides` method:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LoginService provideLoginService() {
    return new FirebaseLoginService();
}
```

Add `Firebase` as a parameter to it and pass it to the `FirebaseLoginService` constructor:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LoginService provideLoginService(Firebase firebase) {
    return new FirebaseLoginService(firebase);
}
```

The constructor:

```
public FirebaseLoginService(Firebase firebase) {
    this.mFirebaseRef = firebase;
}
```

Remove the `@Inject` annotation from your `mFirebaseRef` field since it's not needed anymore.

Here's the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/reustonium/Lunch-Pals/pull/80).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the `FirebaseService` isn't an Android Service proper, it's an API Helper Service.

How would I get a reference to `applicationComponent` within the FirebaseService in order to perform the `.inject(this)` ?

Comment: @Reustonium, I have looked at your repository and have edited my answer.

Comment: @Reustonium, answering your question regarding the `applicationComponent` reference -- it is declared in your `Application` class, so you would have to provide `Context` to the `FirebaseLoginService` and then get it from the `Context`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the PR, you are the best kind of human.